# Logitech USB game controller stops responding on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, logitech-gamepad

I have a Dell PC running Windows Vista. I use a Logitech game controller for the PC to play  different games. The problem is that at random times, it seems the USB port just stops working.  I'll have to unplug and replug it back in. It might work, or it might not. I can go hours or minutes with no problem, then back to the outage...  I don't know too much about PCs, so any help or tips might be great on fixing this.

Side note: The controller works fine on any other PC in the house.

Comment: Is anything else connected to the USB hub the controller is connected to?  And remember, I didn't say *external* hub.  Each port on the computer is not running it's own internal hub.  Multiple USB ports on the motherboard are connected to the same hub, so that (for example) two devices connected to two neighboring USB ports could easily be competing for the same power and bandwidth.

Comment: hmm only things on my pc that are USB is the keyboard mouse and the Logitcech game controller and its a dell studio xps desk top...

Comment: since from your other comment the mouse has issues as well, it may very well be that the mouse and the controller are on the same hub.  try putting the mouse in a different USB port.   Typically, stacked USB ports are on the same hub.

Answer (score 0):

If it works fine on any other computer then it might be a driver issue. Look up the manufacturer and install the driver from their site

Comment: done the driver thing, uninstall and reinstalled the drivers, bios and chip set all match what is current on the dell site

Comment: Well , does this occur with the mouse as well  . Check the logitech site and see if they have any custom drivers that you need to install

Comment: yea it does with the mouse too,  that is how is started

Comment: Then it might be overheating , in which case you can ether keep the room cool or add case fans

Comment: oh trust me my room is cold...... i have a portable AC unit  running  all the time  ( i hate being hot) you think my room is a sever room,  the only other thing  on the net I have found is something about power supply going out will cause the USB ports to shut off???

Comment: had a friend tell me to get a powered  USB hub and use that... but I don't know

Comment: It wont make a different if the usb port is going out . Looks like a hardware defect, which means you cant really do anything to fix it